# POSTMAN request keeps hanging after adding types/cors in Express Typescript

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, express, cors

I have a React web app with Express TypeScript for the backend. I have one POST request so far and it was working well before this.

**issueController.ts**

```
import { RequestHandler } from 'express';
import { Issue } from '../interfaces/issue.interface';

export const createIssue: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  const issue = req.body as Issue;
  res.status(200).json({message: 'issue created successfully', issue})
};
```

**issue.middlewares.ts**

```
import { Issue } from '../interfaces/issue.interface';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

export function validateIssueRequest(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const issue = req.body as Issue;
    if(!issue) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'fail'})
    }
}
```

**issueRoute.ts**

```
import { Router } from 'express';
const router = Router();
import { createIssue } from '../controllers/issueController';
import { validateIssueRequest } from '../middleware/request-validation.middleware';

router.post('/create-issue', validateIssueRequest, createIssue); 

export default router;
```

**index.ts**

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
const port = 3001;
import issueRoutes from './routes/issueRoute';
import cors from 'cors';

const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:5173'];
const options = {
    origin: allowedOrigins
};
app.use(cors((options)));

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening to port ${port}`)
});

app.use('/issue', issueRoutes);
```

Problem is the POST request keeps hanging on Postman but it also does not return any error. My package.json looks like this:

**package.json**

```json
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.25",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1"
  }
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code as I have returned a JSON response.

Comment: Please ignore some errors in file naming as I am unable to edit the post now

Comment: I guess postman would work with CORS 

Comment: @KcH do you mean it wouldn't work? even after i removed cors the post request still hangs. tried it on thunder client and same issue

Comment: I mean postman shouldn't have any cors issues ... not exactly sure whats the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your  `validateIssueRequest` middleware function doesn't return a response and doesn't call the next function. That's why it hangs.

From the Express.js [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html):

> If the current middleware function does not end the request-response
> cycle, it must call next() to pass control to the next middleware
> function. Otherwise, the request will be left hanging.

You need to call `next` function from middleware to pass request cycle to `createIssue`